# Alarm Keep Looping And Making 7000+ Wakelocks, Even After Being Canceled

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms

I'm doing some testing on Alarm, I've setup a basic alarm, with SwitchPreference, When this SwitchPreference is checked, the alarm will turn on and start, when it's un-checked, it will cancel the Alarm.

My problem is, when enabled, it makes up to 11K wakelocks! How did i find out ? using Amplify app which detects Alarms & Wakelocks, After being canceled still the same, when deleted the wakelocks return to 1K .

I don't why, but i think it's looping ? or i'm doing something wrong ?

Here's the Alarm Code :

```
    public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 2, pi);
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
```

And that's how I'm Enabling / Disabling it :

```
        SwitchTest.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                          Object newvalue) {
            boolean Switched = ((SwitchPreference) preference)
                    .isChecked();

            if (Switched) {
                Alarm alarm2 = new Alarm();
                alarm2.SetAlarm(getActivity());
            } else {
                Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
                alarm.CancelAlarm(getActivity());
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

So, What's wrong in it ? I've compared to samples .. nothing weird between them.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You never cancel the alarm you invoked it stays working for ever 
what you could do is to make the setAlaram() method to return that pending intent and cancel it when you want like this.

```
 public PendingIntent SetAlarm(Context context)
{
AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 2, pi);

return pi;
}
```

and where you Enabling / Disabling it change to

```
 SwitchTest.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                                      Object newvalue) {
        boolean Switched = ((SwitchPreference) preference)
                .isChecked();
          Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
        if (Switched) {
            alarm.SetAlarm(getActivity());
        } else {
             alarm.SetAlarm(getActivity()).cancel();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Gonna test it and return to you.

Comment: The Alarm isn't restarting itself again, It's just happening for one time only.

Comment: Plus : static member is accessed via instance reference.